# how to extract actual href of a page which is showing as # when inspecting that page

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a website which has lot of hyperlinks. When i inspect the page, all the href of  showing as '#'.I am not able to extract the actual href .

```
<div class="reportby">
    <a href="#" id="rdToday" class="active" onclick="ViewTodayData()">Today</a>
    <a href="#" id="rdWeek" class="" onclick="ViewWeekData()">Week</a>
     <a href="#" id="rdMonth" class="" onclick="ViewMonthData()">Month</a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: So you need to extract it from javascript

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Are the `#` expected? Are you unsure how to extract the hrefs? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the page is handling the click with the methods `ViewTodayData()`, not with actual `HTML`, you need to go inside the javascript functions and look for the link. If the action is a redirection to another page you should see something like this:

```
function ViewTodayData() {
   window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
}
```